# Networkx cutting of the image

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a graph using NetworkX using the following code:

```
def plotgraph(stringdatafile,alldelays,columns):
        """Plots a temporal causal graph showing all discovered causal relationships annotated with the time delay between cause and effect."""
        G = nx.DiGraph()
        for c in columns:
            G.add_node(c)
        for pair in alldelays:
            p1,p2 = pair
            nodepair = (columns[p2], columns[p1])
            print("nodepair", nodepair)
            # asd
            G.add_edges_from([nodepair],weight=alldelays[pair])
                
        edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
                        for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])
        
        pos=nx.circular_layout(G)
        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels)
        nx.draw(G,pos, node_color = 'white', edge_color='blue',node_size=10000,with_labels = True)
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#000000") 
        pylab.plot()
        plt.savefig("TCDF/result" + "result.png")
```

I am facing few issues:

1. The figure being saved is cut off the saved image: [image: Cutt of image]
2. The node label is going out of node and being cut off. How can I adapt node size to fit the label.
3. Its not displaying the self loops.

Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Why are you using such a large node size? I guess most of your problems will not occur with a lower node size.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the limit of your axis: `ax.set_xlim(-0.1,1.1)` and `ax.set_ylim(-0.1,1.1)`. Because of the size of the nodes, the nodes exceed the normal limits.
2. Change the font size: use `draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=12)` and do not draw the labels in the `nx.draw` command (i.e. set `with_labels = False`)
3. If possible by manipulating the font size you can make the nodes smaller.  This will also show the self loops.